# Bootstrap tooltip left bottom position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my form validation I'm using bootstrap tooltips to show
error message.
 
I adjusted the css to change the appearance (img 1)

```
/* Tooltip */
form .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #843534;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-size: 9px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.tooltip.bottom {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin-top: -6px !important;
}
/* Tooltip arrow */
form .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow,
form .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow,
form .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow,
form .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow {
    border: 0px;
}
```

I would place my tooltip to the left of the element as in img 2, 
but I haven't found a way to do it. (bottom-left not working)

[image]

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/nHcuAXGcQ6)

How would I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Can you please create a JSfiddle of your code? Then we can easily help you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of `left: 529px` use `left: 15px;` on the `#tooltip540283`

Answer (score 2):

According your pen, just add this css to your css

```
.tooltip.fade.bottom
{
  left:30px !important;
}
```

I just use `!important` to override the current left value and you will get your result.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following in your css:

```
.tooltip{
     left:20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify css like below,

```
form .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #843534;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0 0px;
    font-size: 9px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-left: -352px;
}
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 85px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```